# How to integrate numerically the product of result of NDsolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

I am going to integrate the product of the results of `NDsolve`, in fact If x and y are the results as interpolating function, How I can integrate x*y numerically?

```
Table[{Exp[Integrate[ x[t] /. s, {t, 0, i}]]}, {i, -17.5, 10, 1}]
```

This line does not work for products of `x[t]*y[t] or x[t]^2`.

This is my entire code file:

```
yy = {10^-4}; rr = {0.999}; xx = {10^-15}; zz = {10^-4}; mm = {10^-4};

yy + rr + xx^2 + zz - mm^2 - zz^2/24 ic = -17.5

s = NDSolve[{D[y[t], 
     t] == (3 y[t])/5 - (12 m[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (2 r[t] y[t])/
      5 - (6 x[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (3 y[t]^2)/5 + (7 y[t] z[t])/
      5 - (y[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[r[t], t] == -((2 r[t])/5) - (12 m[t]^2 r[t])/5 + (2 r[t]^2)/
      5 - (6 r[t] x[t]^2)/5 + (3 r[t] y[t])/5 + (7 r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (r[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[x[t], t] == (9 x[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 x[t])/5 + (r[t] x[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^3)/5 + (3 x[t] y[t])/10 + (x[t] z[t])/
      5 - (x[t] z[t]^2)/20, 
   D[z[t], t] == 
    12/5 + (12 m[t]^2)/5 - (12 r[t])/5 - (24 x[t]^2)/5 - (18 y[t])/
      5 - (18 z[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (3 y[t] z[t])/10 + (13 z[t]^2)/10 - 
     z[t]^3/20, 
   D[m[t], t] == -2 Sqrt[3] - (6 m[t])/5 - 
     2 Sqrt[3] m[t]^2 - (6 m[t]^3)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] r[t] + (m[t] r[t])/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] x[t]^2 - (3 m[t] x[t]^2)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] y[t] + (3 m[t] y[t])/10 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] z[t] + (6 m[t] z[t])/5 - 
     z[t]^2/(4 Sqrt[3]) - (m[t] z[t]^2)/20, x[ic] == xx, y[ic] == yy, 
   m[ic] == mm, z[ic] == zz, r[ic] == rr}, {x, y^2, z, m, r}, {t, ic, 
   10}]

Table[{Exp[Integrate[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, i}]]}, {i, -17.5, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. For instance, the second line in your complete code dump contains invalid syntax (you can't assign a value to a sum). Can you fix the code so `NDSolve` works first?

Comment: That line is just a constraint equation for physical constraints, one can omit it and `NDsolve` works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

yy = 10^-4;
rr = 0.999;
xx = 10^-15;
zz = 10^-4;
mm = 10^-4;

yy + rr + xx^2 + zz - mm^2 - zz^2/24 
ic = -17.5

s = NDSolve[{D[y[t], 
     t] == (3 y[t])/5 - (12 m[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (2 r[t] y[t])/
      5 - (6 x[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (3 y[t]^2)/5 + (7 y[t] z[t])/
      5 - (y[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[r[t], t] == -((2 r[t])/5) - (12 m[t]^2 r[t])/5 + (2 r[t]^2)/
      5 - (6 r[t] x[t]^2)/5 + (3 r[t] y[t])/5 + (7 r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (r[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[x[t], t] == (9 x[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 x[t])/5 + (r[t] x[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^3)/5 + (3 x[t] y[t])/10 + (x[t] z[t])/
      5 - (x[t] z[t]^2)/20, 
   D[z[t], t] == 
    12/5 + (12 m[t]^2)/5 - (12 r[t])/5 - (24 x[t]^2)/5 - (18 y[t])/
      5 - (18 z[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (3 y[t] z[t])/10 + (13 z[t]^2)/10 - 
     z[t]^3/20, 
   D[m[t], t] == -2 Sqrt[3] - (6 m[t])/5 - 
     2 Sqrt[3] m[t]^2 - (6 m[t]^3)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] r[t] + (m[t] r[t])/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] x[t]^2 - (3 m[t] x[t]^2)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] y[t] + (3 m[t] y[t])/10 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] z[t] + (6 m[t] z[t])/5 - 
     z[t]^2/(4 Sqrt[3]) - (m[t] z[t]^2)/20, x[ic] == xx, y[ic] == yy, 
   m[ic] == mm, z[ic] == zz, r[ic] == rr}, {x, y^2, z, m, r}, {t, ic, 
   10}]

Table[Exp[NIntegrate[(x[t]*y[t]) /. First@s, {t, 0, i}]], {i, -17.5, 10, 1}]
```

> {0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, \
>   0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189482, 0.189488, \
>   0.189548, 0.190091, 0.194979, 0.24302, 0.73482, 1.05174, 1.05889, \
>   1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, \
>   1.05898}

Comment: In fact, I am going to calculate this one:`Table[{Exp[Integrate[ x[t]*y[t] /. s, {t, 0, i}]]}, {i, -17.5, 10, 1}]`

Comment: I updated my response

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, It works correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

You have many superfluous sets of `{}` that generate unexpected output in your code. In particular, the Interpolation functions generated by `NDSolve` were not returning a scalar value, but instead a unidimensional vector, i.e. a list containing a single value instead. That was probably an unintended consequence of the extra sets of braces in the definitions of your numerical constants.

Correct as follows:

```
yy = 10^-4; 
rr = 0.999; 
xx = 10^-15; 
zz = 10^-4; 
mm = 10^-4; 
ic = -17.5;

Table[Exp[NIntegrate[(x[t]*y[t]) /. First@s, {t, 0, i}]], {i, -17.5, 10, 1}]

(* Out:
{0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 
 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189481, 0.189482, 0.189488, 0.189548, 0.190091, 0.194979, 
 0.24302, 0.73482, 1.05174, 1.05889, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898, 
 1.05898, 1.05898, 1.05898}
*)
```

These values seem consistent with the plot of x[t]*y[t]:

```
Plot[(x[t]*y[t]) /. First@s, {t, -17.5, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice also the use of `NIntegrate`, which is specifically geared towards numerical integrations, whereas `Integrate` is best used for symbolic computations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for multiplying `InterpolatingFunctions` generated from a single `NDSolve` (so that the coordinate grids are the same, as well as one-dimensional).  This yields a single `InterpolatingFunction` that interpolates the product.  It carries over derivative information, too.  (I've done this before on the site, I think.)  Anyway, `Integrate` on an `InterpolatingFunction` is accomplished by a built-in rule and is accurate and fast.

```
Clear[multIF];
$dOrder = Sequence[2, 3];
multIF[if1_InterpolatingFunction, if2_InterpolatingFunction] /; 
  Length@if1["Domain"] === 1 && if1["Grid"] === if2["Grid"] :=
 Module[{t},
  Interpolation[
   Transpose@
    Join[{if1["Grid"]}, 
     Table[D[if1[t] if2[t], {t, n}] /. {t -> "ValuesOnGrid"},
       {n, 0, Min[if1[[$dOrder]], if2[[$dOrder]]]}]
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

Since `NDSolve` computes and stores derivative information in the interpolating functions it returns, the `Table` in `multIF` computes the derivative values for the product (up to the derivative order stored).

**Examples**

**Note:** First let `s = First@s`.

```
multIF[x /. s, y /. s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note below that the result from `multIF` complete covers the manual product of `x` and `y`:

```
Plot[{x[t] y[t] /. s,
      multIF[x /. s, y /. s][t], 
      Integrate[multIF[x /. s, y /. s][t], t]} // Evaluate,
  {t, -17.5, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Applying the method to `x[t]^2` works just as well:

```
Plot[{x[t]^2 /. s,
      multIF[x /. s, x /. s][t],
      Integrate[multIF[x /. s, x /. s][t], t]} // Evaluate,
 {t, -17.5, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result of integrating an `InterpolatingFunction` is another `InterpolatingFunction`.  It is equivalent to $F(t) = \int_a^t f(\tau)\,d\tau$, $a \le t \le b$, where $f$ is a `InterpolatingFunction` over $[a,b]$.  It is quite a nice built-in feature.  Converting the product of two `InterpolationFunctions` to a single one takes advantage of this feature.

```
Integrate[multIF[x /. s, x /. s][t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]