# How to Integrate a function of an InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

Let u consider the case (given in Mathematica documentation as an example)

```
ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1},y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

So, you can define a function of `ysol` like

```
y2 = FunctionInterpolation[soly[x]^2, {x, 0, x0}]
```

I'd like to integrate `y2` and later define and `Plot` [image]

where `y^2(x)=y2`. As I said, I'd like to `Plot` `z[x]`. I dont know how to `Integrate` `y2` symbolically in such a way we can `Plot` a function defined as above.

I'd like to refer [question1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119581/integration-of-a-function-of-interpolating-functions) and [question2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/integrating-a-functional-of-an-interpolatingfunction) where this case were asked.

Comment: e.g. `NIntegrate[ysol[x]^2, {x, 0, 30}]`.

Comment: You could do `yzsol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1, z'[x] == y[x]^2, z[0] == 0},{y, z}, {x, 0, 30}]`, but that's not defining it "later."

Comment: You could use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118928/4999) to multiply `ysol` by itself.  Then `Integrate` (not `NIntegrate`) can be used to compute the antiderivative of the result.